# Jacobi symbol problem

Tags: number-theory

Let $n>3\newcommand{\jacobi}[2]{\genfrac{(}{)}{}{}{#1}{#2}}$ be an odd number. Find the value of the Jacobi symbol $\jacobi{n^3}{n-2}$.

I know that
$$\jacobi{n^3}{n-2}=\jacobi{n}{n-2}= \jacobi{2}{n-2} $$
since $\gcd(n,n-2)=1$ and $n\equiv 2 \pmod{n-2}$.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your work is right so far. Now you can finish by applying the so-called "supplemental" rule for the Jacobi symbol:
$$\left(\frac{2}{m}\right)=(-1)^{\frac{m^2-1}{8}}=\begin{cases}
\hphantom{-}1 & \text{if }n\equiv 1,7\bmod 8\\
-1 & \text{if }n\equiv 3,5\bmod 8
\end{cases}$$
([Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_symbol#Properties))